# How do I find the largest circle possible in a square of pixels using Unity?

Tags: mathematics, unity

As I am using Unity, I can easily grab a square of pixels of any length. However, I want to find the largest circle possible within that square of pixels.

So for instance, if I had a 40 x 40 square of pixels, how would I get an array of pixels that form a circle inside of the square?

Comment: Are you just interested in the case of a square? So your question could be simplified to: "How can I draw a rasterized circle?". Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 40×40 square of pixels, you can draw a circle with approximately 40×sqrt(8) pixels.

If you are looking for a circle drawing algorithm to let you pick the pixels to put in your array, an easy way is to draw an eighth of the circle, for instance using the [midpoint algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm), then mirror it three times.